# ordery by clause changes the results returned by avg and max functions

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table:

```
create table dennis_t (name varchar2(20), val int);
insert into dennis_t values ('a',1);
insert into dennis_t values ('a',2);
insert into dennis_t values ('a',3);
insert into dennis_t values ('b',6);
insert into dennis_t values ('c',2);
insert into dennis_t values ('c',3);
insert into dennis_t values ('c',4);
insert into dennis_t values ('c',5);
```

Query below returns the expected result

```
select  name, 
    avg(val) over (partition by name), 
    max(val) over (partition by name)
from dennis_t
```

However if i add an **order by** clause to the analytical function body as so:

```
select  name, 
    avg(val) over (partition by name order by val), 
    max(val) over (partition by name order by val)
from dennis_t
```

the return values would differ from the previous ones, as it would implement a sliding window technique.

Could please anyone explain why this happens? I though that ordering should not matter for aggregates such as avg and max, even though they are being used as analytical functions.

Thanks

Comment: "I though that ordering should not matter" - then why did you *add* it, since that `ORDER` *only* applies to the calculation of those aggregates, and not to the query as a whole. What effect were you *trying* to achieve?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am just playing around with analytical queries atm. No particular reason. Ok, even if it applies to a specific aggregation only - the average should remain the same regardless the order? I am surely missing out something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all covered in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407):

> Some analytic functions allow the ***windowing_clause***. In the listing of analytic functions at the end of this section, the functions that allow the windowing_clause are followed by an asterisk (*).

(Lower in the documentation, both `AVG` and `MAX` are followed by an asterisk)

And:

> If you omit the ***windowing_clause*** entirely, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

So your question:

> the average should remain the same regardless the order?

Is incorrect because, for the first row within the partition, we're only averaging one value (the current row), whereas for later rows within the partition, we're averaging all values previous to the current one plus the current one.

Comment: Thanks Damien. inattentive me in action -_- Have just come across the same exact lines myself.

Comment: As far as I see it, the documentation is not precise. In *both* queries the the windowing_clauses are omitted entirely. So when omitting the windowing clause, there are *two* scenarios: 1) You don't specify an order by clause either, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING. 2) You specify an order by clause, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW. Hence the docs should read "**If you specify an order by clause, but** omit the windowing clause entirely, then the default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW".

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - if you look at the syntax diagram for *analytic_clause*, you'll see that a windowing_clause can *only* be used if an order by clause has been used. There's no windowing without order since "preceding" and "following" don't make sense without an order.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an `ORDER BY val` to `over (partition by name order by val)`, the aggregation (`avg` and `max`) is done on row basis i.e. on all rows till the current row based on `order by val` within the current partition.

For `over (partition by name)`, its calculated for the entire partition once and is not calculated separately for each row within the partition.